# I'm getting an error while generating a signed apk bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have made a simple app in android studio. It builds and runs fine when I test it on an android device, but when I tried to generate a signed apk for the app, This error pops up:

> Entry name 'res/color/material_on_surface_disabled.xml' collided

I have no idea what this error means, and I have no folder named color in the res directory. Please tell me what I should do to resolve this error.

Comment: Clean -rebuild-restart ide

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Not Working :-(

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F : material_on_surface_disabled.xml and check if this has been called somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens sometimes if you are using the older gradle versions
Try updating the gradle version in your project level build.gradle file